# AppCompat Activity doesn't allow import Android.view and there is no getId for ViewCompat

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

Am unable to import Android.view when creating methods for changeColor() in my main activity. Instead it ask me to import ViewCompat and there isn't a getId() in the ViewCompat.

changeColor is an onclick method in my main xml.

Kindly need your advice to get the Resource Id of my radio button to change my text color.

My code is as enclosed below.

```
package com.example.rigmiklos.yt30sharedpreference;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText message;
SeekBar seekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            message.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}

public void changeColor(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.id_red_colour:
            message.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("&FC0116"));
            break;

        case R.id.id_blue_colour:
            message.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("&0810F5"));
            break;

        case R.id.id_green_colour:
            message.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("&03FF20"));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.example.rigmiklos.yt30sharedpreference.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Your Message"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Adjust Font Size"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Font Color"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Red"
            android:id="@+id/id_red_colour"
            android:onClick="changeColor"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blue"
            android:id="@+id/id_blue_colour"
            android:onClick="changeColor"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Green"
            android:id="@+id/id_green_colour"
            android:onClick="changeColor"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Setting"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Setting"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i import Android.view.View to troubleshoot it. Still if anyone got other alternate answer or view, kindly share here.

Comment: So, is this an answer to your own question? If not please delete this and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36116525/edit)

Comment: it is an answer! cause android studio dont auto import this library